# Python: sort an array of dictionaries with custom comparator?

Tags: python

I have the following Python array of dictionaries:

```
myarr = [ { 'name': 'Richard', 'rank': 1 },
{ 'name': 'Reuben', 'rank': 4 },
{ 'name': 'Reece', 'rank': 0 },
{ 'name': 'Rohan', 'rank': 3 },
{ 'name': 'Ralph', 'rank': 2 },
{ 'name': 'Raphael', 'rank': 0 },
{ 'name': 'Robin', 'rank': 0 } ]
```

I'd like to sort it by the rank values, ordering as follows: 1-2-3-4-0-0-0.

If I try:

```
sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=itemgetter('rank'))
```

then the list is sorted in the order 0-0-0-1-2-3-4.

How can I define a custom comparator function to push zeroes to the bottom of the list? I'm wondering if I can use something like [methodcaller](http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/tag/operator/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Option 1:

```
key=lambda d:(d['rank']==0, d['rank'])
```

Option 2:

```
key=lambda d:d['rank'] if d['rank']!=0 else float('inf')
```

Demo:

> "I'd like to sort it by the rank values, ordering as follows: 1-2-3-4-0-0-0." --original poster

```
>>> sorted([0,0,0,1,2,3,4], key=lambda x:(x==0, x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]

>>> sorted([0,0,0,1,2,3,4], key=lambda x:x if x!=0 else float('inf'))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

---

Additional comments:

> "Please could you explain to me (a Python novice) what it's doing? I can see that it's a lambda, which I know is an anonymous function: what's the bit in brackets?" – OP comment

**Indexing/slice notation**:

`itemgetter('rank')` is the same thing as `lambda x: x['rank']` is the same thing as the function:

```
def getRank(myDict):
    return myDict['rank']
```

The `[...]` is called the indexing/slice notation, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) - Also note that `someArray[n]` is common notation in many programming languages for indexing, but may not support slices of the form `[start:end]` or `[start:end:step]`.

**`key=` vs `cmp=` vs rich comparison**:

As for what is going on, there are two common ways to specify how a sorting algorithm works: one is with a `key` function, and the other is with a `cmp` function (now deprecated in python, but a lot more versatile). While a `cmp` function allows you to arbitrarily specify how two elements should compare (input: `a`,`b`; output: `a<b` or `a>b` or `a==b`). Though legitimate, it gives us no major benefit (we'd have to duplicate code in an awkward manner), and a key function is more natural for your case. (See "object rich comparison" for how to implicitly define `cmp=` in an elegant but possibly-excessive way.)

**Implementing your key function**:

Unfortunately 0 is an element of the integers and thus has a natural ordering: 0 is normally < 1,2,3... Thus if we want to impose an extra rule, we need to sort the list at a "higher level". We do this by making the key a tuple: tuples are sorted first by their 1st element, then by their 2nd element. True will always be ordered after False, so all the Trues will be ordered after the Falses; they will then sort as normal: `(True,1)<(True,2)<(True,3)<...`, `(False,1)<(False,2)<...`, `(False,*)<(True,*)`. The alternative (option 2), merely assigns rank-0 dictionaries a value of infinity, since that is guaranteed to be above any possible rank.

**More general alternative** - object rich comparison:

The even more general solution would be to create a class representing records, then implement `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`, and all the other [rich comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), or alternatively just implement one of those and `__eq__` and use the [`@functools.total_ordering` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering). This will cause objects of that class to use the custom logic whenever you use comparison operators (e.g. `x=Record(name='Joe', rank=12)` `y=Record(...)` `x<y`); since the `sorted(...)` function uses `<` and other comparison operators by default in a comparison sort, this will make the behavior automatic when sorting, and in other instances where you use `<` and other comparison operators. This may or may not be excessive depending on your use case.

**Cleaner alternative** - don't overload 0 with semantics:

I should however point out that it's a bit artificial to put 0s behind 1,2,3,4,etc. Whether this is justified depends on whether rank=0 really means rank=0; if rank=0 are really "lower" than rank=1 (which in turn are really "lower" than rank=2...). If this is truly the case, then your method is perfectly fine. If this is not the case, then you might consider omitting the `'rank':...` entry as opposed to setting `'rank':0`. Then you could sort by Lev Levitsky's answer using `'rank' in d`, or by:

Option 1 with different scheme:

```
key=lambda d: (not 'rank' in d, d['rank'])
```

Option 2 with different scheme:

```
key=lambda d: d.get('rank', float('inf'))
```

*sidenote: Relying on the existence of infinity in python is almost borderline a hack, making any of the mentioned solutions (tuples, object comparison), Lev's [filter-then-concatenate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129722/711085), and even maybe the slightly-more-complicated [`cmp` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130207/711085) (typed up by wilson), more generalizable to other languages.*

Comment: Please could you explain to me (a Python novice) what it's doing? I can see that it's a lambda, which I know is an anonymous function: what's the bit in brackets?

Comment: @Richard: of course =) I'll be happy to explain in my answer so everyone can follow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
 sortedlist = sorted([x for x in myarr if x['rank']], key=lambda x: x['rank']) + [x for x in myarr if not x['rank']]
```

bit I guess it could be compressed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more leaning toward creating a compare function to handle the "0" specifically:

```
def compare(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return 0
    elif x == 0:
        return 1
    elif y == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return cmp(x,y)

sorted(myarr, cmp=lambda x,y: compare(x,y), key=lambda x:x['rank'])
```

However, there are performance penalty on the custom compare function.

Comment: This is the `cmp` solution. I like the combined use of `key=` and `cmp=` as an elegant exploitation of the way `sorted`'s parameters work in python. In English this says "`comparing elements left,right by rank: they are equal if their ranks are equal, otherwise left is larger if it's 0 or right is larger if it's 0, otherwise perform the default comparison`". Tragically the first two lines are necessary, otherwise the middle lines would return wrong values before the final `cmp`. The alternative would be removing the top two lines, and doing: `if x==0 and y!=0`...`elif y=0 and x!=0`...`else:`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `cmp` goes away in Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

A hacky way to do it is:

```
sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=lambda x: 99999 if x['rank'] == 0 else x['rank'])
```

This works fairly well if you know your maximum rank.

Comment: This won't work. `itemgetter()` returns a *function*. When you already use a lambda, just use `x['rank']` - you lose the performance advantage of using `itemgetter` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You're `myarr` binding here doesn't look like valid Python code (and doesn't execute in my interpreter session.

Rendering that into:

```
myarr = {
    'Richard': 1,
    'Reuben': 4,
    'Reece': 0,
    'Rohan': 3,
    'Ralph': 2,
    'Raphael': 0,
    'Robin': 0 }
```

Gives me something on which I could base an answer.

The recommended way to do custom sorting in Python is to use the DSU (decorate, sort, undecorate) pattern.
If you want to sort a dictionary by values then that looks something like:

```
keys_sorted_by_val = [ x[1] for x in sorted([(v,k) for k,v in myarr.items()])]
```

... where `(v,k) for k,v in myarr.items()` is the expression to **decorate**; `sorted()` is, obviously, the **sort** and the outer `x[1] for x in ...` is the final **undecorate** step.

Obviously this might seem like a sufficiently common requirement that one might which to wrap this up in a function:

```
def dict_by_values(d):
    return [ x[1] for x in sorted([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()])]
```

If you had a collection of object instances that you want to sort by some attribute you can use something like this:

```
def sort_by_attr(attr, coll):
    results = list()
    for each in coll:
        assert hasattr(each, attr)
        results.append((getattr(each, attr), each))
    results.sort()
    return [x[1] for x in results]
```

So if we created a class representing your name/rank data like this:

```
class NameRanking(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rank):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s: %s, %s" %(self.__class__, self.name, self.rank)
```

... and instantiate a list of those using `myarr`:

name_rankings = [ NameRanking(k, v) for k,v in myarr.items() ]

... then we could get a sorted copy of that using:

```
names_rankings_by_rank = sort_by_attr('rank', name_rankings)
```

(Yes the `assert` isn't a good idea here; that's where you would put in your own exception handling or throwing code as appropriate to your application).

Answer (score -2):

Just give pass to "key" an arbitrary function or callable object - 
it is what it takes. `itemgetter` happens to be one such function -- but it can work
with any function you write - it just has to take a single parameter as input, and return
an object that is directly compable to  achieve the order you want.

In this case:

```
def key_func(item):
   return item["rank"] if item["rank"] != 0 else -100000

sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=key_func)
```

(it can also be written as a lambda expression)

Answer (score -3):

You can use function in key param:

for ass sorting:

```
sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=lambda x: x.get('rank'))
```

or to desc:

```
sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=lambda x: -x.get('rank'))
```

Also you can read about sorted function here http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Because you suggested a stock-standard ascending or descending sort, and the OP wants something slightly different (normal sorting order EXCEPT with the zero-rank elements ordered differently.) You need to read and understand the original question before you post generic answers.

Answer (score -3):

try 
sorted_master_list = sorted(myarr, key=itemgetter('rank'), reverse=True)

Comment: This would give an ordering of `4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0`. The OP wanted `1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0`.